# Почему не работает счётчик обновления страницы

Tags: php, ооп, cookie

Познаю тонкости работы с классами, на этот раз имею удовольствие создать класс для работы с куками, вот, собственно, сам класс:

```
<?php
class CookieShell
{
    public function set($name, $value, $time)
    {
        setcookie($name, $value, $time);
        $_COOKIE[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function get($name)
    {
        return $_COOKIE[$name];
    }

    public function del($name)
    {
        unset($_COOKIE[$name]);
        setcookie($name, null, time());
    }

    public function exists($name)
    {
        return (isset($_COOKIE[$name]));
    }
}
```

Одно из заданий звучит следующим образом: С помощью созданного вами класса реализуйте счетчик обновления страницы, работающий на куках.
Вот так я попытался реализовать этот счётчик:

```
$csh = new CookieShell;

if($csh->exists('counter')){
    $csh->set('counter', $csh->get('counter') + 1, 3600);
} else {
    $csh->set('counter', 1, 3600);
}
echo $csh->get('counter');
```

Но где-то закралась ошибка, которую я не могу найти уже час. Буду благодарен тому, кто ткнёт меня носом в эту самую ошибку.

Comment: 3 параметр в [setcookie](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) не TTL, а Unixtime, то есть секунды с начала 1970 года. У вас дата в прошлом. Добавьте текущий таймстемп

Comment: @TotalPusher блин, я сейчас себе фейспалмом чуть лицо не разбил, сппасибо большое, я бы не скоро догадался

Comment: Я в таких случаях делаю: 1 - минимальный воспроизводимый пример. Путем избавления от лишних деталей. Тут остался бы просто вызов `set`. 2 - ага, ошибка локализована, в браузере кука не ставится. 3 - эксперименты, чтение документации, отладка. Тут я бы проверил, что заголовок с кукой приходит в браузер. А он приходит. Значит он почему-то не ставится. А давайте сверим параметры с документацией...

Comment: @TotalPusher спасибо, звучит весьма последовательно, я запомню :)